# Cube generates unexplainable numbers

Tags: node.js, mongodb, cubes

I'm trying to build a dynamic big data analysis tool using Cube. Thing is, I'm generating test data using this:

```
process.env.TZ = 'UTC';

var util = require("util"),
    cube = require("../../"), // replace with require("cube")
    options = require("./random-config");

util.log("starting emitter");
var emitter = cube.emitter(options["collector"]);

var start = Date.now() + options["offset"],
    stop = start + options["duration"],
    step = options["step"],
    value = 0,
    count = 0;

while (start < stop) {
    emitter.send({
      type: "visit",
      time: new Date(start),
      data: {
        os: "windows",
        ip: "192.168.2.2",
        language: "Dutch",
        article_id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 50)
      }
    });
  start += step * Math.random();
  ++count;
}

util.log("sent " + count + " events");
util.log("stopping emitter");
emitter.close();
```

This way, about 14000 records are being pushed into MongoDB when executed.

When going to `localhost:1081/1.0/metric?expression=sum(visit)&step=1e4&start=2014-01-14T08:00:00Z&end=2014-01-19T08:00:00Z`, however, the data being shown there does not match the data being pushed in. I consistently see ~2000 `visits` when viewing that page and adding the numbers up, causing wildly inaccurate graphs.

Does anyone have an idea or resources about cube? I love the idea of Cube but the lack of documentation makes for a lot of wasted time.

Comment: If you're not getting any ideas on StackOverflow, you could try asking on the [cube-user](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/cube-user) discussion group or possibly raise a [cube github issue](https://github.com/square/cube/issues). It seems like Cube may be in somewhat of a quiscient stage although there have been a few commits as recent as five months ago (Aug, 2013).